# How to log HTTP requests sent by ODataQueryBuilder API / VDM API?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

*Using latest version of Java SAP Cloud SDK*

We have some code which uses `ODataQueryBuilder` API and VDM API as well. We want to log the HTTP requests that are being sent by these API's. We want to log whole of the HTTP request - headers, body everything. Please note that our application is running on SAP Cloud Platform's Cloud Foundry PAAS offering and using `cf set-logging-level doesn't` seem to work.

Comment: What is the application based on? Spring or TomEE? Are you aware of any log implementation provided by you application?

Comment: It's a TomEE application (SAP CAP Application). We use sl4j for logging with logback binding.

Comment: To be precise we use https://github.com/SAP/cf-java-logging-support which uses the things I've mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Can you check whether the following works for you...? [Developing Java in the Cloud Foundry Environment / Logging and Tracing](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/7eb922a1668a435d8bd681263e0be12e.html)

Comment: No it doesn't. I've already mentioned it in my question. It works for all our applcation logs but doesn't work for `ODataQueryBuilder` API and VDM API.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this Java arg when debugging my requests, but I've been doing it locally.

`-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.http.wire=debug`

If you can pass it withing CF environment I think you should start seeing all the payloads. I'll research a bit more to provide a better guidance if this won't work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this approach. I have been able to pass it to CF environment, but the requests from `ODataQueryBuilder` API and VDM API don't get logged.

Comment: Can you post here how you currently pass it? Is it a Spring or Tomee application?

Comment: It's a Tomee application (SAP CAP Application). We use sap_java_buildpack and any command line arguments to JVM can be passed by specifying them in JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_OPTS variable. Here is a sample value for this variable - [java_opts: '-DyourEnvVar -anotherVar']

Answer (score 0):

For applications deployed on SCP CF, there are different setups for which recommend other logging practices. The goal is to configure individual log levels for specific packages of your application and third-party dependencies, e.g. *SAP Cloud SDK* or *SAP Service SDK* or *Apache HTTP components*.

**TomEE** based application:

- Edit the `manifest.yml` to include the following `env` entry for environment variable:

  ```
  SET_LOGGING_LEVEL: '{ROOT: INFO, com.sap.cloud.sdk: INFO, org.apache.http.wire: DEBUG}'
  ```

  Feel free to customize.

**Spring Boot** based application:

- We expect the logback framework.
- Edit/Create the file: `application/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml`

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <springProfile name="!cloud">
          <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
          <root level="INFO"/>
          <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
      </springProfile>

      <springProfile name="cloud">
          <appender name="STDOUT-JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
              <encoder class="com.sap.hcp.cf.logback.encoder.JsonEncoder"/>
          </appender>
          <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
          <logger name="com.sap.cloud.sdk" level="INFO"/>
          <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="DEBUG"/>
          <root level="INFO">
              <appender-ref ref="STDOUT-JSON"/>
          </root>
      </springProfile>
  </configuration>
  ```

  Feel free to customize.
- Notice the different profile settings. Make sure the `cloud` profile is active for deployed applications. Edit the `manifest.yml` to include the following `env` entry for environment variable:

  ```
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'cloud'
  ```